# Spring Batch Rollback full Step instead of current transaction in chunk orientation

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-batch, spring-transactions

I want to read items from the file and insert it into the table. For that, I am using `FlatFileItemReader` and `JdbcBatchItemWriter`. And I am using Chunk Orientation in the step. So my step will look like this.

```
private Step createPoliciesStep() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("CreatePoliciesStep")
                .<PolicyDTO, PolicyDTO>chunk(2)
                .reader(createPoliciesReaderFunc())
                .writer(createPoliciesWriterFunc())
                .listener(createPoliciesWriteListener)
                .listener(createPoliciesStepListener)
                .build();
}
```

I gave commit-interval is 2. So every 2 records commit will happen. For Example, while reading 4th record some exception is throwing. At that time 3rd and 4th records were not inserted, that is absolutely fine. I want to rollback 1st and 2nd records (which commits on the previous transactions) on my table.

> What I am expecting is before step `Begin` the transaction. After step should `commit` the transaction. In between any exception should rollback the entire step.

> We have one simple way, In case of any failure on my next step, I can delete those entries. But I felt it is not a good way to do.

I tried by adding the transaction manager of `DataSourceTransactionManager` and transaction attributes but not working. After adding my step looks like this

```
@Bean
PlatformTransactionManager policyTransactionManager(@Qualifier("mysqlDataSource")DataSource dataSource) {
       return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
}

private Step createPoliciesStep() {
        log.info("Create Policies Step Initiated ");
        DefaultTransactionAttribute attribute = new DefaultTransactionAttribute();
        attribute.setPropagationBehavior(Propagation.REQUIRED.value());
        attribute.setIsolationLevel(Isolation.DEFAULT.value());
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("CreatePoliciesStep")
                .transactionManager(policyTransactionManager)
                .<PolicyDTO, PolicyDTO>chunk(2)
                .reader(createPoliciesReaderFunc())
                .writer(createPoliciesWriterFunc())
                .listener(createPoliciesWriteListener)
                .transactionAttribute(attribute)
                .listener(createPoliciesStepListener)
                .build();
}
```

Can anyone suggest some good method to rollback the full Step. Thanks in advance!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Transaction boundaries in Spring Batch are defined around chunks, not steps. So it is not possible to configure a transaction for the entire step.

A common pattern for your use case is to add a separate step that, based on the exit status of the previous step (success or failure), does a "compensating action" which is rolling back the changes of the previous step in your case.

Comment: I saw one answer, They are doing in ItemWriter extends `StepListenerSupport` and overring the `beforeStep()` method in that setting autocommit false and by Overriding the `afterStep()` method making transaction commit. Is that a good way?. I tried that but the Overriding method is not at all calling, Why?. can u say the use of `StepListenerSupport` in Javadoc not that much clear. Itemwirter class looks like this `public class JDBCWriter extends StepListenerSupport implements ItemWriter<PolicyDTO>`  this its the reference - https://stackoverflow.com/a/48993169/11254983